# Dropzone JS "Server responded with 0 code"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm working with dropzone js and I'm having an issue where in some computers dropzone doesn't make anything.
Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<form action="acciones.php?accion=subirImagenes" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
                        
</form>
```

Dropzone js options:

```
      url: null,
      method: "post",
      withCredentials: false,
      timeout: 30000,
      parallelUploads: 2,
      uploadMultiple: false,
      maxFilesize: 256,
      paramName: "file",
      createImageThumbnails: true,
      maxThumbnailFilesize: 10,
      thumbnailWidth: 120,
      thumbnailHeight: 120,
      thumbnailMethod: 'crop',
      resizeWidth: null,
      resizeHeight: null,
      resizeMimeType: null,
      resizeQuality: 0.8,
      resizeMethod: 'contain',
      filesizeBase: 1000,
      maxFiles: null,
      params: {},
      headers: null,
      clickable: true,
      ignoreHiddenFiles: true,
      acceptedFiles: null,
      acceptedMimeTypes: null,
      autoProcessQueue: true,
      autoQueue: true,
      addRemoveLinks: false,
      previewsContainer: null,
      hiddenInputContainer: "body",
      capture: null,
      renameFilename: null,
      forceFallback: false
```

I compared it on 5 computers with same web browser, and just works in my computer and another one. The strange thing is that when I open console on the other computers that aren't working, there is no http request, not even an attemp on looking for it. Just the message on view that says "Server responded with 0 code"

I don't know what's going wrong, why it works just on some computers...

## UPDATE

It seems to be something about the headers, but I don't know which ones should I include on "headers" dropzone option.

Comment: did you solve this issue in the meantime? I'm struggeling with the same error and actually I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, I just changed the URL and in some way it started to work, don't know the reason though…

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that I successfully resoled by adjusting the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` on my API (server side).

So the easiest solution is to run the Fiddler, or just Firefox Network Inspector (any request \ response monitor will do the job), and monitor the raw request headers, and compare with response `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers.

In my case I was missing `Cache-Control` and `X-Requested-With`, but you make sure that you also have `Content-Type` as well.

Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a server-side method to handle the upload.  Dropzone.js only handles the stuff going on on the client side.  If you have no server side method, you'll continue to get the error message.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I have my php script done, but that is not the issue, it seems that it is a problem with the url because I cannot even see the attempted request on console.

Comment: In your example above, you're setting the `url` property to null.  How would it know what php code to call???  Try taking that out.

Comment: Because the plugin takes the action property from the form tag, it doesn't make sense that in some computer it does upload the file correctly and in some, it doesn't.

Comment: From library file "dropzone.js":
`if (this.options.url == null) {
        this.options.url = this.element.getAttribute("action");
      }
`

Comment: A) Clear the cache in the browser.  B) Make sure there are no toolbars installed (they are a pain) C) If all else fails, install Fiddler on the workstations and compare the HTTP transactions underneath.

Comment: I don't know what the issue was but I solved it by renaming files.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez That sounds like a caching issue.